# What does tagging "Community Wiki" signify?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

What does marking a post or a question as "Community Wiki" signify?

What are the implications? Some stackexchange sites specify that a post marked CW doesn't earn the author any reputation - does a similar rule hold true here as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see:

https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki